# GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException : cURL error 56: LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 60

Tags: php, curl, goutte, guzzle

Why am I getting this error, I'm using "fabpot/goutte": "^3.2" for crawling. Sometimes it gives me correct data but mostly showing this error, what could be the reason.

Below is the complete error.

```
 GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException  : cURL error 56: LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 60 (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

  at /Users/siddharthghedia/code/scraping/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:186
    182|
    183|         // Create a connection exception if it was a specific error code.
    184|         $error = isset($connectionErrors[$easy->errno])
    185|             ? new ConnectException($message, $easy->request, null, $ctx)
  > 186|             : new RequestException($message, $easy->request, $easy->response, null, $ctx);
    187|
    188|         return \GuzzleHttp\Promise\rejection_for($error);
    189|     }
    190|

  Exception trace:

  1   GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle))
      /Users/siddharthghedia/code/scraping/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:149

  2   GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory))
      /Users/siddharthghedia/code/scraping/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:102

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.